# Spoofed? Receiving emails from address that looks like mine

Tags: email, spoofing

My email provider could not help w/ the following.
I am receiving emails from providers who send invoices and reminders to **not_me@my_account.com**
The emails appear in the unrouted email folder since **not_me@my_account.com** is not one of our email accounts.
Apparantly this **not_me** has been placing orders using that email account.
Is this spoofing?
What can I do to delete the **not_me@my_account.com** email address or to avoid this happening again?

Hope somebody knows.

Regards,
Els

Comment: This seem to be off-topic, but I can only say "Welcome to the internet!". There's a fat chance that what you're receiving is just spam. First, there's a good online-tool, which can [trace emails](http://www.ip-adress.com/trace_email/), but you'll need to learn how to use it. If you are sure the "providers" are sending from within EU, then go to their Web-site, check for a phone number and call them. Do *not* click any links inside the emails you receive, or you'll suddenly receive tons of spam.

Comment: Oh, if you just bought the domain recently, then it might be the previous owner who signed up for a bunch of spam (with or without knowing it).

Comment: Thanks PacMan. I did not buy an existing account. <br />I have used the online tool. The email address traces back to my hosting provider. The email account is an account that uses my domain name. The local part however, is not something I have created and I cannot find it in the control panel either. Can you give it one more try?

Comment: Let me understand this correctly; someone is using someone@yourdomain.tld for ordering products on the net. the 'someone' is not an account, which is registered on your email server. If this is the case, then 'someone' is just entering 'someone@yourdomain.tld' as email address on some store site. If I understood it correctly, then that is th store's problem, not your problem, because then the store does not verify email addresses. -If I did not understand it correctly, please correct me. :)

Comment: Yes PacMan: that is exactly what happens. It happens a few times a week. I want stop this 'someone'. Because I see fraude and because my tld is associated with it. The incoming emails from this 'someone' I can see in my unrouted email. For a safer www, there should be a possibility to report or prevent this. Ideas?

Comment: I'd make sure that any emails to someone@yourdomain.tld would be bounced, unless they are a valid email account or a valid forward. This is what I do on my setup. I have *no* "catch-all".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to PacMan, who's answers have directed me towards the following solution.

In the control panel email settings, I have created an email filter.

The filter action I used is: > Fail with message

The message I used is: > Unknown email address.

It's not perfect, but at least the sender will realise that something is wrong and no further orders should be taken from this sender.

Thanx again PacMan.

Comment: If you have an always-on connection and a static IP address, you may want to consider running your own mail-server. I run a modified qmail with Dovecot and Squirrelmail. On the incoming mail, I have spamcop plus my own real-time filtering. It's not an open-relay and I have set it up as secure connection for both POP and SMTP. Thus only someone with a valid account can send mails from my server. It takes quite a while to learn all of it, but take things slowly bit-by-byte, and you'll get there. ;)

Comment: Always make sure your SMTP server is not an open relay. You can use a tool like [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx) for that.

Comment: Thanx again PacMan. I will dive into it soon. Did the mxtoolbox. Good tool. Server is not an open relay.